# Android appcompat-v7:27.1.1 MyLocation not working

Tags: android, geolocation, android-appcompat

I've recently my Android application from appcompat-v7:25.1.1 to v27.1.1.

Subsequently upgraded the Map & Location libraries with:

'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

When i click the 'mylocation' icon in Google Map, i couldn't find the BLUE DOT represented current location. Can't see any error in LogCat.

My gradle dependencies are:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I think you should post your cord here.

Comment: Hi, Haven't write any specific code other than this:

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

The MyLocation Button is appearing in Map, but no effect while click at it.